# How to change color to specific word in Table cell using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I change the color of a specific pattern in table cell text?

Example -

```
 <td>In JSON payload #/end_reason received Values 'normal' , but expected Values -- background, opt_out_tel . ERROR COUNT - 20<td>
```

I need to change the pattern `#/< value>` to different color.

I tried jQuery approach of replacing pattern `#/< value>` with  `<span style='color: rgba(220, 0, 0, 1)'> #/< value> </span>` in controller, but  AngularJS is rendering the literal string rather than changing the color.

Comment: Saranya, could you please share the HTML code which you have tried to debug easily ?

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LZWNbM?

Comment: clicking on any cell, to change background color

Comment: @NagaSaiA, Few lines will be present in a table cell. I need to change color of a word pattern in the line and not the entire line

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option where finding the pattern and highlighting with background red

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-model="change" ng-click="word()">In JSON payload #/end_reason received Values 'normal' , but expected Values -- background, opt_out_tel . ERROR COUNT - 20
          <td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
table tr td{
  border:1px solid black
}

.changeColor{
 background:green; 
}


.highlight
{
background:red;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var tdVal = angular.element(document).find('TD')[0];
  var x = tdVal.innerHTML;
  var text = '#/end_reason';
  var index = x.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    tdVal.innerHTML = x.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + x.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + x.substring(index + text.length);
    console.log(x);

  }

});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXvMwb

Comment: @saranya elumalai, updated with same color mentioned in the post.Check same codepen link for changes. Hope this works for you :)